# Find transcription start sites with biomaRt

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am using `biomaRt` in R to query ensembl's `hsapiens` database of human genes. I am using the function `getBM` to get all genes' name, start position and stop position, but I cannot find the right attribute for retrieving the TSS (transcription start site). Is it maybe because it is considered the same as the `seqType= c("3utr", "5utr")`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A complete list of queriable attributes can be retrieved in a data frame using `listAttributes`. Then it's just a matter of searching it for the attributes you want.

```
mart <- useDataset("hsapiens_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl"))
att <- listAttributes(mart)
grep("transcript", att$name, value=TRUE)
```

will get you a rather long list, begining like this

```
 [1] "ensembl_transcript_id"                                        
 [2] "transcript_start"                                             
 [3] "transcript_end"                                               
 [4] "external_transcript_id"                                       
 [5] "transcript_db_name"                                           
 [6] "transcript_count"                                             
 [7] "transcript_biotype"                                           
 [8] "transcript_status"                                            
 [9] "clone_based_ensembl_transcript_name"                          
[10] "clone_based_vega_transcript_name"
```

Then you can go ahead and query using these names

```
getBM(attributes=c("transcript_start", "transcript_end"),
      filters="hgnc_symbol", values="foxp2", mart=mart)
```

and you get

```
   transcript_start transcript_end
1         113726382      114330960
2         113726494      114271639
3         113726615      114330155
4         113728221      114066565
5         113728221      114271650
6         114054329      114330218
7         114055052      114139783
8         114055052      114333827
9         114055110      114330155
10        114055113      114330200
11        114055275      114269037
12        114055374      114285885
13        114055378      114330012
14        114066555      114294198
15        114066557      114271754
16        114066557      114282629
17        114066570      114294198
18        114055052      114333823
19        114268613      114329981
20        113726615      114310038
```

If you want *all* the transcripts of *all* genes remove the `filter` and `values` arguments, but be aware that you will get a lot of data coming your way.

Comment: Thank you Backlin. My problem was that I had not understood that I needed to get information on each transcript of a gene and I was looking for one TSS for each gene… But from what you say it seems as I will have more than one TSS for each gene... I am not sure this is what I want but I guess it is more of a biology question…

Comment: You're welcome. It is actually very common that genes have multiple start and stop sites and splice variants. I don't know your underlying question, but if you only want to get an overview you could include the transcription count as an attribute and choose the most common for each gene.

Comment: You should also download the attribute "strand". Because the gene used in this example, foxp2, is on the forward strand (strand == 1), the transcription start site (TSS) is the same as the transcript_start. But for genes on the reverse strand (strand == -1), the TSS is the transcript_end.

Answer (score 5):

There is now a specific attribute for the transcription start site that can be downloaded: `transcription_start_site`.

```
library("biomaRt")
ensembl = useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
attributes = listAttributes(ensembl, page = "structure")
attributes[grep("transcript", attributes$description, ignore.case = TRUE), ]
#                         name                                description
# 178    ensembl_transcript_id                      Ensembl Transcript ID
# 183         transcript_start                      Transcript Start (bp)
# 184           transcript_end                        Transcript End (bp)
# 185 transcription_start_site             Transcription Start Site (TSS)
# 186        transcript_length Transcript length (including UTRs and CDS)
# 195         transcript_count                           Transcript count
# 201                     rank                    Exon Rank in Transcript
```

As an example, here is the result for the gene BTC. Note that because it is on the reverse strand (`strand == -1`), the value for `transcription_start_site` is the same as the value for `transcript_end`. Basically, downloading `transcription_start_site` is a shortcut so that you don't have to determine which end of the transcript is the TSS based on which strand the gene is on.

```
tss <- getBM(attributes = c("transcription_start_site", "chromosome_name",
                            "transcript_start", "transcript_end",
                            "strand",  "ensembl_gene_id",
                            "ensembl_transcript_id", "external_gene_name"),
             filters = "external_gene_name", values = "BTC",
             mart = ensembl)
tss
# transcription_start_site chromosome_name transcript_start transcript_end strand
# 1                 75635873     HG706_PATCH         75612096       75635873     -1
# 2                 75660403     HG706_PATCH         75610476       75660403     -1
# 3                 75719896               4         75669969       75719896     -1
# 4                 75695366               4         75671589       75695366     -1
# ensembl_gene_id ensembl_transcript_id external_gene_name
# 1 ENSG00000261530       ENST00000567516                BTC
# 2 ENSG00000261530       ENST00000566356                BTC
# 3 ENSG00000174808       ENST00000395743                BTC
# 4 ENSG00000174808       ENST00000512743                BTC
```

Comment: +1 for the nice answer! May I know how people usually deal with the multiple TSSs per gene in the eQTL analysis? Thanks!

Comment: @Randel That's a better question for a forum like [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/), [Bioconductor](https://support.bioconductor.org/), or [SEQanswers](http://seqanswers.com/). Personally I choose the most upstream TSS for any of the transcripts of a given gene. See this [script](https://github.com/jdblischak/cardioqtl/blob/master/scripts/get-tss.R) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "transcript_start" and "transcript_end" are the translation start and stop site, but not necessarily the TSS (transcription start site).

Looking at the "start_position" and "end_position" attributes, these seem to be the TSS (start_position for + strand and end_position for - strand), because they are always the smallest number of the transcript_start options for different transcript for the + strand and the largest number of the transcript_end options for the - strand.

Comment: transcript_start and transcript_end are the transcription start and transcription end sites for genes on the forward strand, respectively (it is the opposite for genes on the reverse strand). start_position is the most 5' transcript_start of all the transcripts of a gene. end_position is the 3' most transcript_end of all the transcripts of a gene. Thus transcript_start and transcript_end can be different for each transcript of a gene, but they always have the same start_position and end_position.